# Visual Basic 2010 - Multiple Clicks on button cycles throught different background images

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a button cycle through different local background images in Vb 2010

However I am a complete novice at VB and cant figure out how to do this. I want the program to change its background image (cycle through the images in the folder), each time I click the button.

It seems like it should be easy though for the life of me I can't figure it out.

The code below will change it 'once'

```
  Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)   Handles Button2.Click
    BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("C:ProgramIcons\2.jpg")

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Each time you click you need to give it a new file name.  Your code right now only uses a single filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare a global variable near the top of your form like

```
 Dim imageCounter as Integer = 0
```

Then in your `Button Click` you increment the `imageCounter` and then convert it as String using `ToString()` method in order it could be concatenated with File Location and File Extensions which are both are strings.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)   Handles Button2.Click
   imageCounter += 1 ' Increment Image Counter variable
   if (imageCounter> 5) Then ' greater than 5
      imageCounter = 1 ' Reset counter to 1
   End If
      'Convert to string and then concatenate with other string
   BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("C:ProgramIcons\"+imageCounter.ToString()+".jpg")

End Sub
```

Now, this assumes that you have five (5) images thus the comparison `if (imageCounter > 5)`